# Shared objects between windows Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows

I have an application which open several windows (with javascript) in the same domain.

I would like to share some javascript objects between these windows (an object which contains some configurations for example).

Is it possible to do this in javascript and how to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a good candidate for [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Before localStorage, there were cookies

Comment: Cookies length is limited, I don't think I can use cookies for my problem because I want to store objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities: local storage and session storage

The session storage stores value for duration of the session, the value gets deleted when browser is closed and re-opened.

```
// Store value
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
//or
sessionStorage['key'] = value; 
// Retrieve value
alert(sessionStorage.getItem('key'));
```

The local storage stores value beyond the duration of the session, the value can be retrievedeven after closing and re-opening the browser.

```
// Store value
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
//or
localStorage['key'] = value; 

// Retrieve value 
alert(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage` along with `JSON` to store your objects as strings:

Setting:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('yourKey', JSON.stringify(yourObject));
```

Getting:

```
var yourObject = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('yourKey'));
```

the `localStorage` data will be shared across all of your pages as long as they exist in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `window.open()` to create the second window, `window.opener` in the second window might give you access to the first window. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener).